# PHP Undefined property notice

Tags: php

The following array has repeating and non-repeating data.

```
$arr = array();     

//non repeating data
$data = new StdClass();
$data->name = $name;
$data->url = $url;
$arr[] = $data;

//repeating data
foreach($records as $rec) {
    $data = new StdClass();
    $data->text = $rec->text;
    $data->time = $rec->time;
    $arr[] = $data;
}
```

Now I want to retrieve the data of the array, so I'm trying this:

```
echo $arr[0]->name;
echo $arr[0]->url;

foreach ($arr as $rec) {
    echo $rec->text;
    echo $rec->time;
}
```

I get following notice:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$text in xx.php on line 48
```

Line #48 is `echo $rec->text;`

How I can fix this notice instead of hiding it?

Comment: please show $records ?

Answer (score 4):

Your first object from the array has `name` and `url` and the rest have `text` and `time`.

You are getting `Undefined property: stdClass::$text` on the first object, because it does not have that property.

Answer (score 0):

It's just because your static data object doesn't have text and time fields, you can fix this by this simple check:

```
foreach ($arr as $rec) {
    if(isset($rec->text))
        echo $rec->text;
    if(isset($rec->time))
        echo $rec->time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to cornelb's answer you should do it like code below

```
$arr = array();     
foreach($records as $rec) {
    $data = new StdClass();
    $data->text = $rec->text;
    $data->time = $rec->time;
    $data->name = $name;
    $data->url = $url;
    $arr[] = $data;
}
```

or you can start printing values from first index of your array

```
for ($i=1; $i < count($rec); $i++) {
    echo $rec[$i]->text;
    echo $rec[$i]->time;
}
```